# Which Ubuntu version for Dell Precision M4400 notebook

Tags: system-installation, versions

I would like to install Ubuntu on my old **Dell Precision M4400** notebook, but I am not sure on the right version to use.

**Specs:**

- Intel 2.53 GHZ processor
- 2 GB RAM
- NVIDIA Quadro FX 770M, 512MB Graphics card.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu will run on just about any system. There's no need to compare versions, however the desktop might be the problem to keep in mind. If there's issues, right click on the Ubuntu Logo and select `Ubuntu 2D` to use a less resource intensive desktop.

If issues still arise, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> will call up the console. Login and put in `tasksel` and use the arrow keys to navigate around to find Ubuntu Desktop. Press space to uncheck it and select a different desktop that'll work for you. Examples are Lubuntu, Xubuntu, and so forth. Press enter when you are done to install the new desktop before rebooting.

Optionally, if the 2D Desktop is working as I suggested, you might want this as default for all users and future users, so opening a terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and putting in `sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s ubuntu-2d`

Answer (score 0):

If you need **improved and latest version** You should **wait for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Release Date 17 April 2014**

Because Long Term Support Versions are better than another versions.

14.04 **will made available from 17 April 2014** and will support till 2019.

Just wait for some days for that amazing version.